# Two linear maps are "identical"

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I'm trying to describe a situation, whose smallest example is the following (coefficients in the original problem are some horrible expressions):

We're given a linear map $\phi$ with:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \\z \\w\end{bmatrix} \mapsto_\phi \begin{bmatrix} 2x + y \\3y + x \\2z + w \\3w + z\end{bmatrix}
$$

This map $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ is just two copies of "the same" map combined by "direct product".

What would be appropriate words for "the same" (something like isomorphic?) and "combined" here? I'm particularly interested in following reasoning:

> To compute eigenvectors of $\phi$ it is sufficient to study it's action on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as it's "the same" as action on the second $\mathbb{R}^2$

So stating that they have identical eigenvalues and therefore are isomorphic is the opposite of what I need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map is a product of maps: if you have $f:E\to F$ linear and $g:G\to H$ linear, then you have a map $f\times g:E\times G\to F\times H$ given by $(f\times g)(u,v)=(f(u),g(v))$. An eigenvalue of $f$ induces an eigenvalue for $f\times g$ (take an eigenvector $u_\lambda$ for $f$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $(u_\lambda,0)$ is an eigenvector for $f\times g$ associated to the same eigenvalue $\lambda$), and same for $g$. You are in the special case where $E=F=G=H=\mathbb{R}^2$, and $f=g$ the same linear map.

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a name of this type of sameness and product. Is this "direct product of maps" and "maps are isomorphic"? If so is there a name for required isomorphism (canonical, coordinate, ...)?

Comment: Here, "same" is to take literally: from the linear map $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\varphi(u,v)=(2u+v,3v+u)$, you are creating a new map $\phi:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$ by defining $\phi$ as the direct product of the maps $\varphi$ and $\varphi$, namely $\phi=\varphi\times\varphi$. I think that direct product of maps is the correct term, perhaps it is inscribed in some richer category theory vocabulary.

Comment: I was hoping for a more descriptive word, one that would suggest which kind of sameness is actually important here (the linear-spacey kind and not for example metric or topological kind). Well, at least I know I'm not missing something obvious.

Comment: Same (or equal) does take care of the structure: for example, $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the space of polynomials of degree $1$, $\mathbb{R}[X]$, could be thought as the same vector space since they are of finite dimension $2$ and so linear isomorphic, but the induced sets are not the same. So when you say that two vector spaces are equal, you actually say that the spaces are equal, the additions are the same maps, the scalar and the exterior multiplications are the same one too, so you actually care about the structure.